# Position fixed en columna aside no funciona

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema similar al de mi compañero alberto: [Columna fixed bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229043/columna-fixed-bootstrap)

Quisiera dejar la columna `<aside>` estática igual que la cabecera de menu, pero no logro solucionarlo, ya apliqué position:fixed y static. Estuve viendo sobre affix, pero creo que no funciona en la version 4 de Boostrap. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la `<aside>` sea estática?

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas con el template oficial de bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/blog/

Comment: Hola, el código que estoy usando es el del enlace del Blog, lo que quiero dejar estático es <aside class="col-md-4 blog-sidebar">

Comment: ¿cuál columna `<aside>`? No veo ninguna en el código de la otra pregunta. De hecho sería más sencillo si agregas tu código a esta pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz entiendo que se refiere a este <aside> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU83A.png

Comment: @JheymanMejia aún así el código debería estar acá.

Comment: Muchas hracias hermano @JheymanMejia por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basandome en el ejemplo citado en [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/252764/position-fixed-en-columna-aside-no-funciona#comment469413_252764) y en respuesta a la pregunta

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la `<aside>` sea estática?

#### Solución:

Para que el contenido dentro del `<aside>` permanezca visible mientras se *scrollea*, lo que puedes hacer es agregar dentro del un `<div>` con la clase [`sticky-top`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/#sticky-top) el cual deberá contener todo lo que se desea que se mantenga visible.

#### Ejemplo

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/blog/blog.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <header class="blog-header py-3">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 pt-1">
        <a class="text-muted" href="#">Subscribe</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <a class="blog-header-logo text-dark" href="#">Large</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <a class="text-muted" href="#">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="mx-3" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Search</title><circle cx="10.5" cy="10.5" r="7.5"/><path d="M21 21l-5.2-5.2"/></svg>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
    <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">World</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">U.S.</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Technology</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Design</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Culture</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Business</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Politics</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Opinion</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Science</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Health</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Style</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Travel</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron p-4 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
      <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">Title of a longer featured blog post</h1>
      <p class="lead my-3">Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.</p>
      <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Continue reading...</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">Featured post</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">Design</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">Post title</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 11</div>
          <p class="mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 blog-main">
      <h3 class="pb-4 mb-4 font-italic border-bottom">
        From the Firehose
      </h3>

      <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

        <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
        <hr>
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur
          purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
        <blockquote>
          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong> ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </blockquote>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
        <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
          nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</li>
          <li>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
          <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
        <ol>
          <li>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</li>
          <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
          <li>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</li>
        </ol>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.blog-post -->

      <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">Another blog post</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">December 23, 2013 by <a href="#">Jacob</a></p>

        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur
          purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
        <blockquote>
          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong> ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </blockquote>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.blog-post -->

      <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">New feature</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">December 14, 2013 by <a href="#">Chris</a></p>

        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
          nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</li>
          <li>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
          <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.blog-post -->

      <nav class="blog-pagination">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Older</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Newer</a>
      </nav>

    </div>
    <!-- /.blog-main -->

    <aside class="col-md-4 blog-sidebar">
      <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="p-4 mb-3 bg-light rounded">
          <h4 class="font-italic">About</h4>
          <p class="mb-0">Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="p-4">
          <h4 class="font-italic">Archives</h4>
          <ol class="list-unstyled mb-0">
            <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
          </ol>
        </div>

        <div class="p-4">
          <h4 class="font-italic">Elsewhere</h4>
          <ol class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>

    </aside>
    <!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</main>
<!-- /.container -->

<footer class="blog-footer">
  <p>Blog template built for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Back to top</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

***Nota:** Para verlo funcionando, deben ejecutar el snippet en "Página completa".*

Answer (score 3):

Este es un ejemplo usando `Bootstrap 4`:

Asignamos la clase `fixed-top` al `<aside>` y la clase `sticky-top` al `div` que envuelve la barra superior (Cabecera o Menú).

```css
.logo, .cabecera{
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-2 px-0 fixed-top" id="left">
            <div class="row bg-dark">
                <div class="col-2 py-4 logo">
                  <h3>Logo</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group w-100">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            </div>

        </aside>
        <main class="col-10 invisible">
            <!--hidden spacer-->
        </main>
        <main class="col offset-2 h-100">
            <div class="row bg-dark sticky-top">
                <div class="col-12 py-4 cabecera">
                    Cabecera o Menú
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-white">
                <div class="col-12 py-4">
                    Lorem Ipsum

                    <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut
                        semiotics, raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave
                        meditation. Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>

                    <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
                        readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch
                        selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El problema es cuando el aside está posicionado debajo de la cabecera, y no a un lado y a la misma altura.

Comment: @JheymanMejia agregué un pequeño `div` con características similares al de `cabecera` dentro del `aside`. Ese espacio se puede usar para agregar un logo, por ejemplo.