# CCS como empezar a escribir donde quiero

Tags: css, laravel-blade

Estoy creando una plantilla con laravel y tengo las barras de menú que quiero pero no consigo que un simple encabezado me lo ponga donde realmente quiero siempre me lo escribe debajo de el menú dejo una captura de ejemplo y el código que llevo hasta ahora a ver si me podéis ayudar en que me falta para tenerlo.

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper deep-purple lighten-3">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div>
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav sidenav-fixed">
    <li><div class="user-view">
            <div class="background deep-purple lighten-3">
            </div>
            <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="https://www.waspcom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/user-placeholder-circle-1.png"></a>
            <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
            <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
        </div></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que toda la estrucutra de la web se pinte en las lineas amarillas y no como ahora que me sale debajo de los menus.

Comment: Creo que es un tema de maquetación. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/252764/position-fixed-en-columna-aside-no-funciona/267908#267908) hay un ejemplo que quizás te puede ayudar _a pesar de estar basado en `Bootstrap`_. Si te fijas, hay un `<div>` que encierra todo, dentro está el `<aside>` con la parte lateral izquierda y el `<main>` que contiene un  `<div>` interno con el encabezado _en tu caso el menú_ y otro `<div>` interno con la parte del texto.

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente estructura es un diseño básico solo por **HTML CSS** pero que puede ayudarle a entender la posición de los objetos en su marco de trabajo usando el **Framework Laravel**.

El contenido que insertas no queda en la posición que usted desea debido que siempre está abarcando el **100% de su pantalla**, teniendo presente que el menú del lado izquierdo tiene un tamaño **(width y height establecidos)** por tanto el contenido debe tener un **width menos el tamaño de su menú izquierdo** y lo mismo aplica para el tamaño del **menú superior.**

Para que lo comprendas más le dejo un ejemplo de lo posiblemente buscas, puede realizarlo por su propio **CSS** o puede recurrir a la información de uso de Laravel y verificar si una clase en específico ya permite el correcto posicionamiento de las cajas.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .menu {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: purple;
    color: #FFF;
}

.container .barra {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    right: 0;
    background: blueviolet;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    color: #FFF;
}

.container .content {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    top: 10vh;
    height: 90vh;
    background: palevioletred;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Documento de prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">
            MENU PRINCIPAL
        </div>
        <div class="barra">
            MENU BARRA
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            TEXTO
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Si observa cuidadosamente la clase **menú** tiene un `width: 300px y un height: 100vh` (100% de largo disponible).

La clase **barra** tiene `position: absolute` para romper su flujo y con `top: 0` se envía a la parte de arriba de la pantalla. Con la instrucción **CSS Calc** le digo al `Width` que tenga un `100%` y se le resta los `300px` del tamaño de menú izquierdo.

```
width: calc(100% - 300px);
```

La clase **.content** tiene un **top** de `10vh` que es el mismo tamaño de la clase barra se le asiga `90vh` para completar el `100vh` de toda la pantalla y se hace la misma resta mostrada anteriormente.

Hay que tener presente que si el `z-index` de sus menús son superiores a contenedor del texto también la información quedara oculta, de ser así cambia asigna un `z-index` superior al contenido.

Espero sea de utilidad.